# What was the first file system in Linux distribution/s?

Tags: linux, filesystems, history

What was the first file system in Linux distribution/s?
The "parallel" to FAT (?) in Windows at the early nineties?

I want to know the name to read information about this; perhaps it was the same one utilized in Unix ([Unix filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#:%7E:text=In%20Unix%20and%20operating%20systems,version%20of%20Unix%2C%20dated%201969.)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Linux initially used [the MINIX file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX_file_system), and very early distributions relied on that. [The extended file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_system) quickly took over, followed by [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) and [xiafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiafs) (which was never much developed, and ultimately disappeared in favour of Ext2).

It was also possible to run Linux on FAT, using [umsdos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT_filesystem_and_Linux#umsdos).

Comment: And even older is [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System), but it is rather the domain of Unix than Linux.